# PHP type juggling clarification

Tags: php

Can someone explain why this is returning true?

I tried removing any one character and it returns false but exactly this code returns true I cannot understand why

`var_dump('608E-4234' == '272E-3063');`

Comment: The strings are NOT equal. Equality `==` is comparing them. So when you say they are "true", how do you mean?

Comment: Ok I tried your code. It does indeed return `true`. Interesting. Could be an anomaly of `var_dump`.

Comment: Its not `var_dump()`. Something is going on with the assignment comparison. Good cacth ChethanB. Never saw this before. Im thinking some "hex" operaration, maybe legacy.

Comment: `if ('608E-4234' == '272E-3063') echo "hello";` returns "hello". Possibly some legacy or a PHP bug. (PHP 7.3.16). I found the decimal values, they do not correspond to an operation happening.

Comment: These strings are compared as floates, as answer below said. If you want to compare them as strings, use `===`.

Answer (score 3):

PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) says:

> If both operands are numeric strings, or one operand is a number and the other one is a numeric string, then the comparison is done numerically

In this case you're trying to compare 2 floats:

```
var_dump((float) '608E-4234'); // double(0)
var_dump((float) '272E-3063'); // double(0)
```

The reason why those floats are equal is that their values out of precision settings. Try to compare `272E-306`:

```
var_dump((float) '272E-306'); // double(2.72E-304)
```

and you'll see another result.